# Update Query MSSQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-update

```
UPDATE Record  SET Record.CreateID = c.CreateID
FROM  @RecordIDList  r ,@CreateIDList c  
WHERE r.ID = Record.ID
```

Here `@RecordIDList` and `@CreateIDList` are the Output Clause acting as the scope identity for multiple rows this query is working fine the only issue i am facing now is if `@RecordIDList` has 5 Ids for record it is updating the Recording table but updating it with same `c.CreateID` for all 5 rows and its putting the top 1 `c.CreateID`.
Am i missing any thing or doing some thing wrong? I am using SSMS 2014

```
Record.ID  | Content | CreateID
-------------------------
         1 | Khar    | 1
         2 | SantaCr | 2
         3 | Sion    | 3
         4 | VT      | 4
         5 | newFort | 5
         6 | Bandra  | 6
         7 | Worli   | 7


 CreateID  | Date       | 
-------------------------
         1 | 21-09-2017 |  
         2 | 21-09-2017 | 
         3 | 21-09-2017 | 
         4 | 21-09-2017 | 
         5 | 21-09-2017 | 
         6 | 21-09-2017 | 
         7 | 21-09-2017 |
```

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: As for the question hand we would need something to work with. Sample data and table structure at the very least.

Comment: @SeanLange Two birds, one stone ;)

Comment: @Sami I guess in my case it was two stones, one bird? Figured I could hit it from multiple sides that way. :)

Comment: Is this really your actual query?   It should raise a syntax error.

Comment: @TabAlleman I don't see the syntax error. What is invalid about it?

Comment: References to `Record` when there is no `Record` in the FROM clause.

Comment: @TabAlleman the syntax isn't an issue there but there is a HUGE logical issue. It would just update every row in Record to the same thing.

Comment: So what do you suggest

Answer (score 0):

Are @RecordIDList and @CreateIDList table variables? If so, this will update @RecordIDList from matching records in @CreateIDList:

```
UPDATE r
    SET r.CreateID = c.CreateID
FROM @RecordIDList  r
    JOIN @CreateIDList c 
        ON c.ID = r.ID
```

Comment: See the table structure